# how to block/disable words in the search field?

Tags: magento2, custom-block, magento2.4.3.p1

I'm having a search with inappropriate words in Magento, how can I block it?

Comment: which type of search world do you want to block/disable so please explain.?

Comment: inappropriate words (offenses) or referring to games (bet, casino...)